# Direction angle of Line segment in polar coordinates

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I have a line segment given by two points $A$ and $B$, that are $(r_1,\theta_1)$ and $(r_2,\theta_2)$ in Polar coordinates.

I know that the direction angle of the line segment is given by:

$$\theta_0=\begin{cases}
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y2-y1}{x2-x1}\right),  & x_1\ne x_2 \\
\frac{\pi}2, & x_1=x_2
\end{cases}
$$

where $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are the points $A$ and $B$ in Cartesian coordinates.

Is there any way to get $\theta_0$ without converting to Cartesian coordinates?